# Image Classification Deep Learning Model shows high accuracy but gives wrong prediction

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have trained a deep learning model for image classification using CNN and CIFAR 10 Dataset. It has 10 classes, and goes on for 50 epochs. The accuracy shown after training is completed is 96.02% and validation accuracy is 96.96%. But when I pass an image to it for detection and testing it shows wrong answers even to the pictures in which the object is obvious. For example: it detects the frog as automobile or airplane, deer as airplane or horse, and birds as cat or dog.

I have already tried to train it with more neurons. Then I thought maybe its because I am training the model on grayscale images and passing colored images, so I then trained it on colored images and it showed the same results.

```
import os
from datetime import time
from random import shuffle

#import TensorBoard as TensorBoard
#import TensorBoard as TensorBoard

import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from random import shuffle
from tqdm import tqdm
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

TRAIN_DIR = '../input/dataset/Train'
TEST_DIR = '../input/dataset/Test'
IMG_SIZE = 32
LR = 1e-3  # 1x10^-3 or 0.003
MODEL_NAME = 'image classifier'
def create_label(image_name):
    """ Create an one-hot encoded vector from image name """
    word_label = image_name.split('_')[1:2]
    word_label = word_label[0].split('.')[0:1]
    word_label = word_label[0]
    if word_label == 'cat':
        return np.array([1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
elif word_label == 'dog':
    return np.array([0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
elif word_label == 'automobile':
    return np.array([0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
elif word_label == 'airplane':
    return np.array([0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0])
elif word_label == 'ship':
    return np.array([0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0])
elif word_label == 'frog':
    return np.array([0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0])
elif word_label == 'truck':
    return np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0])
elif word_label == 'bird':
    return np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0])
elif word_label == 'horse':
    return np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0])
elif word_label == 'deer':
    return np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1])


def create_train_data():
    training_data = []
    for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR)):
        path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
        img_data = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        img_data = cv2.resize(img_data, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
        training_data.append([np.array(img_data), create_label(img)])
    shuffle(training_data)
np.save('train_data.npy', training_data)
return training_data


def create_test_data():
testing_data = []
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TEST_DIR)):
    path = os.path.join(TEST_DIR, img)
    img_num = img.split('.')[0]
    img_data = cv2.imread(path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    img_data = cv2.resize(img_data, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    testing_data.append([np.array(img_data), img_num])

shuffle(testing_data)
np.save('test_data.npy', testing_data)
return testing_data

# If dataset is not created:
train_data = create_train_data()
test_data = create_test_data()

# If you have already created the dataset:
#train_data = np.load('train_data.npy')
#test_data = np.load('test_data.npy')
train = train_data[:50000]
test = train_data[:10000]
X_train = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y_train = [i[1] for i in train]
X_test = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
y_test = [i[1] for i in test]

# Building The Model

tf.reset_default_graph()
convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 3, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 3)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 3, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 3)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 256, 3, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 3)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 128, 3, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 3)
convnet = conv_2d(convnet, 64, 3, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 3)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 1024, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.8)
convnet = fully_connected(convnet, 10, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR,   loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')
model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log', tensorboard_verbose=2)
history = model.fit({'input': X_train}, {'targets': y_train}, n_epoch=50,
      validation_set=({'input': X_test}, {'targets': y_test}),
      snapshot_step=1250, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25, 12))

for num, data in enumerate(test_data[:50]):

img_num = data[1]
img_data = data[0]

y = fig.add_subplot(10, 10, num + 1)
orig = img_data
data = img_data.reshape(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)
model_out = model.predict([data])[0]

if np.argmax(model_out) == 0:
    str_label = 'Cat'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 1:
    str_label = 'Dog'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 2:
    str_label = 'Automobile'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 3:
    str_label = 'Airplane'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 4:
    str_label = 'Ship'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 5:
    str_label = 'frog'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 6:
    str_label = 'truck'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 7:
    str_label = 'bird'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 8:
    str_label = 'horse'
if np.argmax(model_out) == 9:
    str_label = 'deer'
    #if condition ends here

y.imshow(orig, cmap='gray')
plt.title(str_label)
y.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
y.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)  #for loop ends here

plt.show()
"""saving the model using tflearn"""

model.save('CNN.tfl')

# I am using the following code for testing purpose

global a
img_data1 = cv2.imread(a, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
img_data1 = cv2.resize(img_data1, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
data1 = img_data1.reshape(IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
model_out = model.predict([data1])[0]
if np.argmax(model_out) == 0:
    str_label = 'Cat'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 1:
        str_label = 'Dog'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 2:
        str_label = 'Automobile'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 3:
        str_label = 'Airplane'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 4:
        str_label = 'Ship'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 5:
        str_label = 'frog'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 6:
        str_label = 'truck'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 7:
        str_label = 'bird'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 8:
        str_label = 'horse'
    if np.argmax(model_out) == 9:
        str_label = 'deer'
```

"a" is the image passed to it, the code is picked from the GUI made on TK-Inter and a gets the path of the image and passes it on to the model.

I am annoyed to see that the accuracy shown at the end of training is so high and still the predictions I get by the model while testing are so wrong even for the obvious images. 

 if someone can help me out with this problem, I'll be grateful.

 Thanks !!

Comment: i think you should read images as colored (if they indeed are colored) and convert to grayscale (using `cv2`) before training or testing.

Comment: @NikosM.i tried that too, but that did not work either. I got same predictions as i was getting before.